# Gesture typing suggestions in Google Now

Tags: keyboard, 4.2-jelly-bean, google-now, gesture-typing

With the 4.2 update, I've begun using the default Android keyboard's gesture typing. However, I've noticed that in Google Now, the keyboard behaves as if it were a web browser. That is, it doesn't offer alternate suggestions when typing a word.

For example, my girlfriend's name is Brooke. If I'm attempting to pull up her contact details through Google Now, the keyboard interprets my gesture as "broke." But, if I use the same gesture in any other place (besides a web browser address bar) it offers me "Brooke" as an alternate suggestion. What I mean is this:

[image: Search for "Brooke" in Google Now]

vs. this:

[image: Search for "Brooke" in web search]

Is there a way to fix this? I know that I could work around by typing individual letters or using last names, but it's rather frustrating to have to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there is any way to do this.

This must have been hard coded into the Google Now app - as that is the only way they will act like this.

The only way would be to contact Google and ask them to change it in their app.

Comment: Blah. I was afraid that might be the case. I was just hoping I was missing something. Also, thanks for adding the gesture-typing tag. I tried to do so but don't have enough rep on this site to create new tags.

Comment: No worries about the tag - I added the tag wiki as well, just need to wait for it to be reviewed. On an on topic note, this annoys me on search apps as well - it does the same with the swype keyboard.

Comment: Weird. I had been using TouchPal prior to the 4.2 update and it works just fine on Google Now. I may just go back to it and see if Google figures out how to make their keyboard work right down the road.

Comment: I just use Chrome to search for anything I'd have used Now for had it worked.  Not sure why Chrome doesn't have an option for its Awesomebar or whatever it's called to do all the stuff the Now textbox does.